# How to find Marginal pdf?

Tags: probability

$f_{XY}(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
3x & 0\leq x \leq 1, x-1 \leq y \leq 1-x  \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise }
\end{array}\right.$

How to find $COV(X,Y)$?

for that I need to find Marginal densities of X and Y.

$f_X(x)=\displaystyle \int_{y=x-1}^{1-x} 3x~dy =3x(1-x)(x-1), \mbox{ for } 0\leq x \leq 1$

$f_Y(y)=\displaystyle \int_{x=0}^{1} 3x~dx =\frac{3}{2}(1-0)=\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}, \mbox{ for } -1\leq y \leq 1$

Are these Correct? Please tell me if incorrect.

Comment: Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]. To find E[X] we need $f_X$

Comment: Oh, true. Silly me.

Comment: For the first one, you should have $3x((1-x)-(x-1))=6x(1-x),$ for the second, you should only be integrating from $x=0$ to $1-|y|,$ which you can see by rearranging the inequalities $x-1\leq y\leq 1-x.$

Comment: Xe at least needs to find the boundaries for one.  The boundaries for the first are okay, though not the integration

Comment: "To find E[X] we need fX" Well... no, we do not, since $$E(X)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{0<x<1~,~ x−1≤y≤1−x\}$ is also $\{-1\leq y\leq 1~,~ 0\leq x\leq y+1~,~0\leq x\leq 1-y\}$ and thus $\{-1\leq y\leq 1~,~0\leq x\leq 1-\lvert y\rvert\}$.

$$\mathsf E(1) ~=~ \int_0^1 \int_{x-1}^{1-x} 3x\mathop{\rm d}y\mathop{\rm d}x ~=~ \int_{-1}^1\int_0^{1-\lvert y\rvert}  3x\mathop{\rm d}x\mathop{\rm d}y ~=~1 \quad\text{(test: pass by two)}$$

$$\mathsf E(X) ~=~ \int_0^1 \int_{x-1}^{1-x}x\cdot 3x\mathop{\rm d}y\mathop{\rm d}x ~=~ \int_{-1}^1\int_0^{1-\lvert y\rvert} x\cdot 3x\mathop{\rm d}x\mathop{\rm d}y$$

$$\mathsf E(Y) ~=~ \int_0^1 \int_{x-1}^{1-x}y\cdot 3x\mathop{\rm d}y\mathop{\rm d}x ~=~ \int_{-1}^1\int_0^{1-\lvert y\rvert} y\cdot 3x\mathop{\rm d}x\mathop{\rm d}y$$

$$\mathsf E(XY) ~=~ \int_0^1 \int_{x-1}^{1-x}xy\cdot 3x\mathop{\rm d}y\mathop{\rm d}x ~=~ \int_{-1}^1\int_0^{1-\lvert y\rvert} xy\cdot 3x\mathop{\rm d}x\mathop{\rm d}y$$

Integrate by whatever path is easiest.

Comment: Thank you. Now how can we decide whether X and Y are independent? where as its getting Cov(X,Y)=0.

Comment: $\int_{x-1}^{1-x} 3x\mathop{d} y\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1}\cdot\int_{0}^{1-\lvert y\rvert} 3x\mathop{d}x\cdot\mathbf 1_{-1\leq y\leq 1} ~\overset{?}=~ 3x \mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1, x-1\leq y\leq 1-x}$

Comment: are you asking me to check this $6x(1-x) . \frac{3}{2}(1-|y|)^2 = 3x$? Of course NOT.

Comment: There's your answer then.  (Hmm.  You could also observe that as the conditional support of $Y$ is restricted to varying intervals depending on the value of $X$ there is a dependency.)